# Pandas - How to swap column contents leaving label sequence intact?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas v0.25.3. and am inexperienced but learning.
I have a dataframe and would like to swap the contents of two columns leaving the columns labels and sequence intact.

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({"A": [(1),(2),(3),(4)], 
                    'B': [(5),(6),(7),(8)], 
                    'C': [(9),(10),(11),(12)]})
```

This yields a dataframe,

```
    A   B   C
0   1   5   9
1   2   6   10
2   3   7   11
3   4   8   12
```

I want to swap column contents B and C to get

```
    A   B   C
0   1   9   5
1   2   10  6
2   3   11  7
3   4   12  8
```

I have tried looking at pd.DataFrame.values which sent me to numpy array and advanced slicing and got lost. 
Whats the simplest way to do this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign numpy array:

```
#pandas 0.24+
df[['B','C']] = df[['C','B']].to_numpy()
#oldier pandas versions
df[['B','C']] = df[['C','B']].values
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(B = df.C, C = df.B)
```

---

```
print (df)
   A   B  C
0  1   9  5
1  2  10  6
2  3  11  7
3  4  12  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also swap the labels:

```
df.columns = ['A','C','B']
```

If your DataFrame is very large, I believe this would require less from your computer than copying all the data.

If the order of the columns is important, you can then reorder them:

```
df = df.reindex(['A','B','C'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just use:

```
df['B'], df['C'] = df['C'], df['B'].copy()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C
0  1   9  5
1  2  10  6
2  3  11  7
3  4  12  8
```